# Using awk or sed add a line based on a pattern match

Tags: awk, sed, find-replace

A have a file containing SQL migration commands. For example

```
// admin_setting
$this->createTable('{{%admin_setting}}', [
    'setting_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . "(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    'short_description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . "(255) NOT NULL",
    'value' => Schema::TYPE_TEXT . " NULL",
    'PRIMARY KEY (setting_id)',
], $this->tableOptions);

// authorization
$this->createTable('{{%authorization}}', [
    'authorization_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . "(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    'short_description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . "(255) NULL",
    'PRIMARY KEY (authorization_id)',
], $this->tableOptions);
```

I want to add another command before the line containing the "createTable() command, so that my example file will look as follows :-

```
// admin_setting
$this->dropTable('{{%admin_setting}}');
$this->createTable('{{%admin_setting}}', [
    'setting_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . "(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    'short_description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . "(255) NOT NULL",
    'value' => Schema::TYPE_TEXT . " NULL",
    'PRIMARY KEY (setting_id)',
], $this->tableOptions);

// authorization
$this->dropTable('{{%authorization}}');
$this->createTable('{{%authorization}}', [
    'authorization_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . "(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    'short_description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . "(255) NULL",
    'PRIMARY KEY (authorization_id)',
], $this->tableOptions);
```

I am seeing lots of examples to delete lines matching a pattern, but none so far that can get me the above changes.

The closest I came is

```
   awk '/createTable/{print "$this->DropTable();"}1' file
```

but I cannot fill in the contents inside the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/createTable/{h;G;s//dropTable/;s/, \[/);/}' file
```

Copy the line containing `createTable`, then append the copied line and pattern match and replace on the first occurrence.

Comment: Works great for me. Would you mind taking the time to explain the h;G parameters.

Comment: @crafter the `h` command copies the current line to a register known as the hold space (HS). The `G` command appends the contents of the HS to the pattern space (PS) which is the register holding the current line. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands).

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with the field delimiter in `awk`. Setting it to a single quote, you can access the desired value in field 2:

```
awk -F"'" '/createTable/{print "$this->dropTable('\''"$2"'\'');"}1'
```

sed's `s` can also be used:

```
sed 's/\$this->createTable(\('\''[^'\'']*'\''\)/$this->dropTable(\1);\n\0/'
```

It's a bit tricky to escape the single quotes. Alternatively you can enclose the command with double quotes, however, in that case you need to take care on preventing the shell from interpreting the `$`:

```
sed "s/\\\$this->createTable(\('[^']*'\)/\$this->dropTable(\1);\n\0/"
```

Comment: Both should work. They just differ in the use of single or double quotes.

Comment: Use the single quoted version but instead of jumping in and out of shell (that's what you're doing, btw, not escaping the single quotes) just use the escape sequence `\047` everywhere you want a single quote, e.g. `print "$this->dropTable(\047"$2"\047);"`. In this case you could alternatively have used `print "$this->dropTable("FS $2 FS");"`.

Answer (score 1):

A GNU awk solution:

```
/createTable/ {
    match ($0, /createTable\('(.*)',/, x)
    print "$this->dropTable('" x[1] "');"
}

{
    print $0
}
```

edit: used the suggestions, noting that this is GNU awk, and removed unneeded print from the first block, tks.

note: I think the whole {print $0} may be replaced by '1' (single character '1'), but I believe readable is better than short here.

Comment: Note that this requires GNU awk for the 3-argument match() function

Comment: DRY: remove the `print $0; next` from the first block

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ new = $0 }
sub(/createTable/,"dropTable",new) {
    sub(/,.*/,");",new)
    print new
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
// admin_setting
$this->dropTable('{{%admin_setting}}');
$this->createTable('{{%admin_setting}}', [
    'setting_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . "(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    'short_description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . "(255) NOT NULL",
    'value' => Schema::TYPE_TEXT . " NULL",
    'PRIMARY KEY (setting_id)',
], $this->tableOptions);

// authorization
$this->dropTable('{{%authorization}}');
$this->createTable('{{%authorization}}', [
    'authorization_id' => Schema::TYPE_INTEGER . "(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
    'short_description' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . "(255) NULL",
    'PRIMARY KEY (authorization_id)',
], $this->tableOptions);
```